# Script element not working inside JQuery .append()

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using this loop in Javascript:

```
$.get('showplaylist.php', {playlist: "inbox"}, function(data){

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i++)
        {

            var key = i;

            var id = data[key]['id'];

            var youtubeid = data[key]['youtube_id'];

            videoThumb(id, youtubeid);

        }
        }, "json");

});
```

The function I am looping through unpacks id and youtubeid and appends html output for each line. e.g.

```
function videoThumb(id, youtubeid)

$('#videos').append(

        "<ul id=\"sortable\">" +
            "<li id='item_" + id + "' class=\"ui-state-default\">" +
                "<div class=\"thumb\" id=\"" + id + "\">" +
                    "<img src=\"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/" + youtubeid + "/default.jpg\">" +
                "</div>" +
            "</li>" +
        "</ul>"

        );
}
```

}

The problem is the "sortable"  element. I am using JQuery UI sortable plugin. When I generate the html with PHP (without using Javascript) the sortable plugin works. Generating the html through the above function means that it doesn't.

The sortable plugin is defined like this:

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
            stop: function(i) {
            placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "updatedb.php",
                data: $("#sortable").sortable("serialize")});
            }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Any ideas about how to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you binding the sortable plugin?

Comment: Hi, not sure what that means. Have updated original question with plugin

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect `id`. All your appended elements have the same id:

```
$('#videos').append(

    "<ul id=\"sortable\">"
```

Or you just appending to incorrect element. I think, the code should be:

```
$('#sortable').append(
    "<li id='item_" + id + "' class=\"ui-state-default\">" +
        "<div class=\"thumb\" id=\"" + id + "\">" +
            "<img src=\"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/" + youtubeid + "/default.jpg\">" +
        "</div>" +
    "</li>"
);
```

Your code gives incorrect html structure:

```
<!-- video 1-->
<ul id='sortable'>
    <li><img/></li>
</ul>
<!-- video 2-->
<ul id='sortable'>
    <li><img/></li>
</ul>
```

But correct html should look like this:

```
<ul id='sortable'>

    <!-- video 1-->
    <li><img/></li>

    <!-- video 1-->
    <li><img/></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I want to append to <div id="videos></div> elsewhere in the page.

Comment: Don't forget to tick answer ;)